# Update counter using xparse command with argument processing

Tags: counters, xparse

I recently started using xparse and I want to update the value of a counter with the output of an xparse command. The xparse command uses argument processing which seems to pose a problem. Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\newcounter{counterC}
\newcommand\StandardAdd[2]{\the \numexpr #1 + #2}
\NewDocumentCommand\xparseAdd{mm}{\the \numexpr #1 + #2}
\NewDocumentCommand\xparseProcessAndAdd{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{:}} m}{\xparseAdd #1 }

\begin{document}

    Without xparse: \addtocounter{counterA}{\StandardAdd{2}{3}} \arabic{counterA}\\
    With xparse: \addtocounter{counterB}{\xparseAdd{2}{3}} \arabic{counterB}\\
    %With xparse argument processing: \addtocounter{counterC}{\xparseProcessAndAdd{2:3}} \arabic{counterC}\\
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
Without xparse: 5
With xparse: 5
! Missing number, treated as zero. \xparse function is not expandable
```

When I use argument processing (splitting the argument into tokens) inside a counter's update, Latex does not compile. The error message is the one described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: An aside question: Why would you want to supply `2:3` and not actually `2+3`?

Comment: Yes, of course it's not expandable. (anyway, obviously it's not expandable, so the answer is passing the counter name into the macro to be set; or make the macro set some predefined macro to the result instead)

Comment: @Werner I was working with times and was too caught in to take a step back.

Comment: @user202729 I followed your advice and it fixed my problem. I have been using TeX for a long time but never stopped to think about tokens and expandability. Do you recommend the TeXbook ?